# Get the duration of videos stored in a S3 bucket

Tags: macos, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there an easy/efficient way of get the duration of about 20k videos stored in a S3 Bucket?

Right now, I tried mounting the bucket in OS X using expandrive and running a bash script using [mediainfo](http://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) but I always get a "Argument list too long" error.

This is the script

```
#! /bin/bash
# get video length of file.
for MP4 in `ls *mp4`
do
    mediainfo $MP4 | grep "^Duration" | head -1 | sed 's/^.*: \([0-9][0-9]*\)mn *\([0-9][0-9]*\)s/00:\1:\2/' >> results.txt
done
# END
```

Answer (score 2):

ffprobe can read videos from various sources. HTTP is also supported - this should help you as it lifts the burden to transfer all files to your computer.

```
ffprobe -i http://org.mp4parser.s3.amazonaws.com/examples/Cosmos%20Laundromat%20faststart.mp4
```

Even if your S3 bucket is not public you can easily generate signed URLs which allow time limited access to an object if security is of concern. 
Use [Bucket GET](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) to get all files in the bucket and then execute the ffprobe with appropriate filtering on all files.

This answers your question but the problem you are having is well explained by Rambo Ramone's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `xargs` instead of the for loop. The backtics run the command and insert its output at this spot. 20K files are probably too much for your shell.

```
ls *.mp4 | xargs mediainfo | grep "^Duration" | head -1 | sed 's/^.*: \([0-9][0-9]*\)mn *\([0-9][0-9]*\)s/00:\1:\2/' >> results.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If mounting the S3 bucket and running mediainfo against a video file to retrieve video metadata (including the duration header) results in a complete download of the video from S3 then that is probably a bad way to do this. Especially if you're going to do it again and again.

For new files being uploaded to S3, I would pre-calculate the duration (using mediainfo or whatever) and upload the calculated duration as S3 object metadata.

Or you could use a Lambda function that executes when a video is uploaded and have it read the relevant part of the video file, extract the duration header, and store it back in the S3 object metadata. For existing files, you could programmatically invoke the Lambda function against the existing S3 objects. Or you could simply do the upload process again from scratch, triggering the Lambda.